# How to get color on ubuntu on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bash

When I click the icon or run `ubuntu` from the command prompt there's no color in the prompt. But if I run `bash` in the ubuntu program there's color. How do I get color automatically on program startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol you have to:

`source ~/.bashrc`

and it will work.